# What is the kernel of the summation map from the direct sum to the sum?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $I_1,\ldots,I_n$ be ideals in $R$ (or submodules of some $R$-module). Consider the sequence
$$
\bigoplus_{1\leq j < k\leq n} I_j\cap I_k\quad\xrightarrow{f}\quad\bigoplus_{l=1}^n I_l\quad\xrightarrow{g}\quad\sum_{k=1}^n I_k,
$$
where $g$ is given by addition, and $f$ maps $x\in I_j\cap I_k$ to $x\in I_j$ and to $-x\in I_k$ (and to zero in all other components).

Clearly, $g$ is surjective and the composition $g\circ f$ vanishes.

**Question:** Is the above sequence exact in the middle?

(This seems to be easy for $n=2$.)

(Concerning the title: I am aware of the fact that $f$ won't be injective in general.)

Comment: Your sum is unclear: is the sum over all ordered pairs $(j,k)$, all ordered pairs with $j\lt k$, all ordered pairs with $j\leq k$? Something else? E.g., for $n=2$, do you have just $I_1\cap I_2$, or $I_1\oplus (I_1\cap I_2)\oplus I_2$, or $I_1\oplus(I_1\cap I_2)\oplus (I_2\cap I_1)\oplus I_2$?

Comment: @Arturo: edited. The sum is over all pairs; however, on summands with $j=k$, the map $f$ will vanish anyway.

Comment: Actually, all variants Arturo suggests give the same image. Maybe, it is nicest, to take only ordered pairs with $j<k$. Edited accordingly.

Comment: As discovered in the follow-up to this question, for commutative rings the property is equivalent to the ring being arithmetical. For Noetherian domains, it is equivalent to it being Dedekind. So, non-integrally closed rings such as $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ provide simple counterexamples. For the follow-up question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21170/does-the-ring-of-integers-have-the-following-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert chandok's example to ideals in a commutative ring as well.  Take R=**Z**[x,y,z]/(3,xx,xy,xz,yy,yz,zz), a 4-dimensional algebra over Z/3Z.  It has ideals of (vector space) dimension 1 generated by x−y, y−z, and z−x.  There is clearly a non-zero kernel of "g" containing the triple ( x−y, y−z, z−x ).  However, the domain of "f" is 0, since all pairwise intersections of the ideals are 0.

The obvious translation of chandok's example to one over the ring **Z**<sup><sup>3</sup></sup> fails, since the ideals generated by the x<sub>i</sub> get bigger.  This ring fixes that, since it has a bunch of pointless ring elements that leave most abelian subgroups as ideals.

Comment: interesting example -- thanks! Is there also an example for ideals in a (not necessarily commutative) algebra over the complex numbers?

Comment: Oh sure!  R=C[x,y,z]/(x,y,z)^2 (tangent something-something at (0,0,0) in the 3-dimensional affine space).  The ideals are 1-dimensional (as vector spaces) with generators  x−y, y−z, and z−x.  Everything works the same (for any field I think, I just chose the smallest where the things looked normal).

Answer (score 3):

If you take $I_1, \ldots I_n$ submodules of an $R$-module $M$, you can easily find a counterexample when their intersection is zero :

Pick $R = \mathbb{Z}, M = \mathbb{Z}^3, x_1 = (1,-1,0), x_2 = (0,1,-1), x_3 = (-1,0,1)$.
Then you have that $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 0$, $x_i$ is in its submodule $I_i = \mathbb{Z}x_i$, and for $i \not = j, I_i \cap I_j = \{0\}$.