# Does the ring of integers have the following property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, homological-algebra

As a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21017/), I'd like to ask:

What are examples of rings $R$ with the property that for all finite sets of ideals $I_1,\ldots,I_n$ in $R$ the sequence
$$
\bigoplus_{1\leq j < k\leq n}^n I_j\cap I_k\quad\xrightarrow{f}\quad\bigoplus_{l=1}^n I_l\quad\xrightarrow{g}\quad\sum_{k=1}^n I_k
$$
is **exact in the middle**? Here $g$ is given by addition, and $f$ maps $x\in I_j\cap I_k$ to $x\in I_j$ and to $-x\in I_k$ (and to zero in all other components).

A complete description of this class of rings would be even better, of course.

Obvious examples seem to be rings with at most two proper ideals. Those I would consider pathological in this context.

I'd be happy to restrict to complex algebras if that is useful.

Also, is there a name for rings with this property?

---

**Edit:** *In order to make the question more answerable, let's just consider the case $R=\mathbb Z$. Can we find ideals in $\mathbb Z$ such that the above sequence is not exact, or can we prove that this is impossible?*

Comment: Do you know *any* example apart from that one?

Comment: @Mariano: My question is inspired by the fact, that, for a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, I think that $C_0$ (continuous functions vanishing at infinity) gives a cosheaf on $X$ with values in the lattice of closed ideals of $C_0(X)$. And there is the result that all closed ideals of $C_0(X)$ are of the form $C_0(U)$ for an open subset of $U$. Of course I cheated by restricting to closed ideals.

Comment: I hope it's ok to change the question, in order to make it more localised. After all, there haven't been any answers until now. I added the number-theory tag because I think the question for $R=\mathbb Z$ is in fact number theory.

Comment: The example in my previous comment generalises to arbitrary C*-algebras because the lattice of closed ideals is isomorphic to the lattice of open subsets of the primitive ideal space and therefore distributive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see that your property does hold in $\mathbb{Z}$. In fact, it holds in any principal ideal domain, and even in every [Dedekind domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain).

[**Edit:** As pointed out by Rasmus below, for the commutative case, the property is equivalent to the ring being [arithmetical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_ring). This is because arithmetical rings are defined by the distributive lattice property I state in (2) below. So, for integral domains, the property is equivalent to the ring being [Prüfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_domain). This certainly includes all Dedekind domains and, in the case of Noetherian domains, it is actually equivalent to the ring being Dedekind.]

I think it's just as easy to start by considering an arbitrary ring $R$. Choosing any $x\in\bigoplus_kI_k$ such that $g(x)=0$, then we have $x_1=-\sum_{k\ge2}x_k\in I_1\cap\sum_{k\ge2}I_k$. Conversely, if $x_1\in I_1\cap\sum_{k\ge2}I_k$ then this can be extended to an $x\in\bigoplus_kI_k$ with $g(x)=0$.
We want this to mean that there exists a $y\in\bigoplus_{j < k}I_j\cap I_k$ with $f(y)=x$. This implies that $x_1=\sum_{k\ge2}y_{1k}\in\sum_{k\ge2}I_1\cap I_k$. So, a necessary condition for the given sequence to be exact in the middle is that
$$
I_1\cap\sum_{k=2}^nI_k\subseteq\sum_{k=2}^nI_1\cap I_k.\qquad\qquad{\rm(1)}
$$
The reverse inclusion is immediate for any ring. In particular, just considering $n=3$ gives the necessary condition
$$
I\cap(J+K)=I\cap J+ I\cap K,\qquad\qquad{\rm(2)}
$$
for all ideals $I,J,K\subseteq R$. In fact, this is both a necessary and sufficient condition. It can be seen that your original condition and (2) are both just statements about a collection of subgroups of an abelian group (here, the group is $R$ under addition and the subgroups are the ideals). In fact, you are asking when the first homology group of a specific chain complex vanishes (much like in [Cech cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cech_cohomology)). Also, (2) is the same as saying that the ideals form a [distributive lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice) $({\rm Id}_R,+,\cap)$. However, I'm no expert in this, and don't know what the name of rings satisfying your particular condition is (Edit: In the commutative case, these are *arithmetical* rings as mentioned above and in a comment below).

To see that (2) implies (1), use induction for $n\ge2$,
$$
I_1\cap\sum_{k=2}^nI_k=I_1\cap\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}I_k+I_1\cap I_n=\sum_{k=2}^nI_1\cap I_k.
$$

To see that (1) implies exactness, consider $x\in\bigoplus_kI_k$ with $g(x)=0$. Then, $x_n\in I_n\cap\sum_{k < n}I_k=\sum_{k < n}I_k\cap I_n$. So, there will be a $y\in\bigoplus_{j < k}I_j\cap I_k$ with $y_{jk}=0$ for $j < k < n$ and $f(y)_n=x_n$. Replacing $x$ by $\tilde x=x-f(y)$ reduces to the case with $\tilde x_n=0$, so exactness follows by induction on $n$.

Finally, (2) holds in any Dedekind domain. It is clear if any of $I,J,K$ are zero, so suppose that they are nonzero. For any ideal $I$ and nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, write $v_{\mathfrak{p}}(I)$ for the index of $\mathfrak{p}$ in the factorization of $I$ (the $\mathfrak{p}$-adic valuation). Two nonzero ideals $I,J$ are equal if and only if $v_{\mathfrak{p}}(I)=v_{\mathfrak{p}}(J)$ for all primes $\mathfrak{p}$. Then, using $v_{\mathfrak{p}}(I+J)=\min(v_{\mathfrak{p}}(I),v_{\mathfrak{p}}(J))$ and $v_{\mathfrak{p}}(I\cap J)=\max(v_{\mathfrak{p}}(I),v_{\mathfrak{p}}(J))$ implies that (2) holds.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_ring is a kind of ring involving distributivity of the ideal lattice in its definition.

Comment: @Rasmus: Well discovered!